# Merge existing iPhone contacts to my iCloud

Tags: icloud

Due to switching between iOS and Android over the years my contacts have been strewn about between all the services I use. The current situation I'm dealing with is that about half of my contacts are on iCloud, and the other half are coming from my Gmail account that I setup through the Settings app. I'm kind of OCD with this stuff so I would prefer to have them ALL on either iCloud or Gmail.

I don't know of an easy way to do this. In the iPhone Contacts app I can turn on/off two groups, the iCloud group and Gmail group. But there is no "merge" or "sync" option. Am I SOL? Apparently you can do this easy with a Mac but I haven't had access to one since college.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I was lucky and actually had contacts in my Gmail account separate from my iCloud (no overlap or duplicates between the two). So I just exported from Gmail in vCard form and then used the iCloud web interface (www.icloud.com) to import them into my Contacts. Everything is working great now.